# Why am I told that I have reached my daily vote limit when I have only made 36 votes today?

Tags: support, votes

I just did some voting on some new questions, and this appeared:

[image: Daily vote limit reached, but only 36 votes made]

I often reach my vote limit, so I was not surprised, however, note that I have only issued 36 votes today. Is there some specific restriction that I have triggered, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vote limit used to just be 30 votes in a day, but it got a little more confusing when they added [10 extra votes for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89534/separate-vote-pools-for-questions-and-answers) (and then [changed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256)) to try and encourage question voting. Now you can get up to 40 votes in a day (30 regular votes + 10 extra question votes), but once you're low enough on regular votes to start getting the "you're nearing the vote cap" warning, that's it -- you have that many remaining. So you can end up not getting the full 40 depending on the order you vote on things

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did initially take a look at the `voting` tag on SO meta, but didn't see these. This seems a rather overcomplicated system, but at least I know what's going on now.